# C# WPF ListView how to scroll on specific button press

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, scroll

I am implementing horizontal scroll into my ListView, it works but I need to scroll horizontally with mouse wheel.

I got so far that I know how to catch if the mouse wheel was scrolled up/down but I just need a command that will activate scroll left/right.

```
 private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView listView= (ListView)sender;
         
            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {
                // Scrolls right, I need here to activate event that will scroll right,
                // something like listView.ScrollRightByOneItem()
            }
            else
            {
               // Scrolls left, I need here to activate event that will scroll left,
               // something like listView.ScrollLeftByOneItem()
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

XAML

```
  <Grid>
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NotDeletedDevices}"
            MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick"
     PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
            PreviewMouseMove="ListView_PreviewMouseMove"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            PreviewMouseWheel="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseWheel"
            TouchDown="ListView_PreviewTouchDown"
            TouchMove="ListView_PreviewTouchMove">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
  </Grid>
```

Is there any event that will let me scroll to the right or left by 1 item?

I need a command/event that will let me scroll to the right/left in the .xaml.cs file

Comment: could you show your xaml file?

Comment: its important to know where is defined your scrollbar over the listview on inside the listview...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have defined a name to Listview `lview`  (i think no need to define Scrollviewer, its automatically `Auto` i think)

```
    <ListView x:Name="lview" Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="100"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              PreviewMouseWheel="ListViewer_PreviewMouseWheel"/>
```

As the scrollbar belongs to Listviewer, you have to find its instance so i define a method `FindScrollViewer`:

```
    private ScrollViewer FindScrollViewer(DependencyObject d)
    {
        if (d is ScrollViewer)
            return d as ScrollViewer;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(d); i++)
        {
            var sw = FindScrollViewer(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(d, i));
            if (sw != null) return sw;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void ListViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        //find the scrollViewer instance of the control
        var scrollViewer = FindScrollViewer(lview);

        //get the horizontal value
        var h = scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
        // check the delta of wheel mouse >0 or <0
        var d = e.Delta;
        var nv = 0d;
        // are you at the beginning or end the scrolling
        if (d < 0)
        {
            nv = d + h < 0 ? 0 : d + h;
        }
        else
        {
            nv = d + h > scrollViewer.ScrollableWidth ? scrollViewer.ScrollableWidth : d + h;
        }
        // to block the vertical move
        scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
        //set the new horizontal position
        scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(nv);
    }
```

i just show how to block the vertical move when you want to move the scrollbar horizontally.

you can choose a keyboard (for example) to switch between horizontal/vertical

Comment: Wowww, thank you. The only good answer and so simple to implement. I was struggling for hours to get it work but nothing. Much appreciated Frenchy! <3

Comment: @Walde no problem happy to help you..so to close the question dont forget to upvote/validate the answer...

Comment: @Frenchy Don't you think the delta should be divided by some divider? One notch of wheel produces 120 and it would be too fast. I implemented this feature in my answer to OP's previous post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76020121/3137337

Comment: yes of course you could rate the speed of scroll..Some mouse  (mine for example) can change this value with a special switc on the mouse..you could play too with the offset you add